# Puppet master reverts back to older state and installs incorrect config/software

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster

Has any one seen an issue with Puppet where we deployed some new configuration changes in the morning, but much later in the day it looks like the configuration was reverted.  At least one package had the wrong version installed and some firewall rules were not applied.  As far as we can tell, nobody was on the system around the time when the problems occurred.  All of the logs we looked at all looked normal.

We are running version 3.7.2.

Apologies for being vague, but that's really all I have.  I'm hoping someone has seen something similar and can point me in the right direction to debug it.

Comment: Are you running Puppet through Passenger? Could this be some kind of caching issue with long running Ruby master processes? If this keeps happening, could you try `puppetserver` instead?

Comment: Thanks.  It is running passenger.  I'll pass the info along as I'm not the one who controls the server.